# Best practice for caching values in large project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest

I'm working on a fairly large project. There are 2 cases that I need to handle
 1. Some values like API key, BaseURLs for API calls are fetched once from DB and resued in multiple places in the solution (In different classes).
 2. Some values are fecthed using an API call and might change sometimes, so I need to make API calls sometimes to refresh these values and then resue.
 My solution for case 1 right now is to `create a staic constructor` that fetches values once from DB and is reused. Is it a good solution? What's the best practice in such cases? And how do I handle case 2? What is the best practice for such 'caching'?

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class called `CachedDataAccessor` and implement the following behavior in it.

1. `GetCachedData()` that would return API key, Urls in your case, stores a copy of it the first time it fetched data from the db
2. `RefreshCachedData()` to refresh expired values and fetch them from db.
   Thereafter you can also implement `CacheSize` to allow the size of the cache to be configurable.

And every time you need the data, fetch it from the `CacheAccessor`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the classes in system.runtime.cahching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

For both cases you could use the MemoryCache object.

in the first case you can set the SlidingExpiration of the CacheItemPolicy too something like an hour, so when it get's hit it won't be removed from cache.

in the second case, if you want to cache data for a certain time you can set the AbsoluteExpiration to that time.

If you know the conditions of when the cache needs to be cleared, you can create a change monitor that will cleare the cashe items when the data in cache is invalid.